# Dielectric in an external electric field

Tags: pde, simulation, electromagnetism

I want to numerically solve for electric field of an object in an external electric field. The object has linear displacement field such that its permitivity ($\epsilon$) is constant. The object's shape is not important but I would prefer an ellipse. I do not know how should I impose curl and divergence equations into simulation as well as boundary conditions.

What I need is electric field or charge density. Does anyone know how can I calculate charge density of a dielectric ellipse in an external electric field?

Comment: I rewrote your question, I changed the word "matter" for "object", since I believe that makes more sense. Please check the new version, though.